# Prometheus client storage

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to instrument my golang application with prometheus and was wondering where does the "client" store the data. I understand that the server stores the data in its own TSDB. However, it is not clear to me where does the client running in my golang application will store the metrics data?

Answer (score 2):

It's all kept entirely in memory, and will go away when the process dies. Prometheus functions like `rate()` are designed to handle this.

Comment: I thought so, but did not find any documentation on it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Does the client app have to retain the data in memory indefinitely? Or can it prune older data? Thinking specifically about counters that are expected to be monotonically increasing. Just want to make sure I understand your point about rate(): it sounds like the client app does not need to retain them, as long as it exposes the data for any time series that had changed?